# Clustering with parameterized metrics

Tags: clustering, hyperparameter, metric

Let's assume that we have some data $x_1,x_2,\dots x_n$.

Moreover, we have a parameterized distance metric $\delta(x,x';\theta)$ for some $\theta\in \Theta$.

That's it, I have no labels, no clue about number of clusters,... How to determine the best $\theta$ that can explain the data best.

Without loss of generality, we can consider the case when $\Theta=\{\theta_1,\theta_2\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can try visualizing your data set under each metric using techniques like t-SNE or diffusion maps.  Compare the pictures.  Without quantifying what it means for a metric to "best" suit a data set, there's not much else to try.